# Tampermonkey / UserScript load images/css from another domain

Tags: subdomain, tampermonkey

I've just installed Tampermonkey as an addon for Chrome. What I want to accomplish is to create a userscript which will allow me to load CSS and image files from another (sub)domain. Something like "subdomain2.domain.com"  ... Is that even possible? Thanks!